# Cannot sorting joined column in Magento Grid

Tags: grid, sorting, join

I have joined 2 columns to customer grid, I can make them filterable but I don't know how to make them sortable.
Here is my _prepareCollection function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
      ->addNameToSelect()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
      ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
      ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id');
    $collection->addSalesInfoPerCustomer();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

My joined function:

```
public function addSalesInfoPerCustomer() {
    $this->getSelect()
      ->joinLeft(
        array('s' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total) total_sales, COUNT(*) as order_count, customer_id'
          . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
          . ' GROUP BY customer_id)')),
        "s.customer_id = e.entity_id",
        array('total_sales', 'order_count')
      );
  }
```

Added Column:

```
$this->addColumn('order_count', array(
      'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
      'index' => 'order_count',
      'filter_index' => 'pages_with_number_of_views.order_count',
      'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_roleFilter'),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('total_sales', array(
      'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Sales'),
      'index' => 'total_sales',
      'type' => 'price',
      'currency_code' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
      'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_roleFilterTotalSales'),
    ));
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Follow this link, you'll get the answer: 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73353/cannot-sorting-joined-column-in-magento-grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have founded the answered after a few days. The solution for this kind of problem is added this function to grid: (overwrite _setCollectionOrder in parent grid class).

```
protected function _setCollectionOrder($column)
  {
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    if ($collection) {
      $columnIndex = $column->getFilterIndex() ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
      if($columnIndex == 'pages_with_number_of_views.order_count')
      {
        $columnIndex = 'order_count';
        $collection->getSelect()->order($columnIndex.' '.strtoupper($column->getDir()));
      }
      if($columnIndex == 'total_sales'){
        $collection->getSelect()->order($columnIndex.' '.strtoupper($column->getDir()));
      }
      else{
        $collection->setOrder($columnIndex, strtoupper($column->getDir()));
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

Comment: I really appreciate this :)