# How do I make this custom expression column I have developed for the customer grid display sortable?

Tags: grid, sorting, customer-grid, join-table, sort

I'm trying to add an expression column to collection in customer grid. But it not sortable. I'm not sure that using addExpressionAttributeToSelect or addExpressionFieldToSelect function can solve this problem. I don't know how to use them in my case.

As now,my code looks like as follows: (or view my old question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73353/cannot-sorting-joined-column-in-magento-grid))

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
      ->addNameToSelect()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
      ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
      ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id');
    $collection->addSalesInfoPerCustomer();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

**My joined function:**

```
public function addSalesInfoPerCustomer() {
    $this->getSelect()
      ->joinLeft(
        array('s' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT sum(o.base_grand_total) total_sales, COUNT(*) as order_count, customer_id'
          . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
          . ' GROUP BY customer_id)')),
        "s.customer_id = e.entity_id",
        array('total_sales', 'order_count')
      );
  }
```

**Added Column:**

```
$this->addColumn('order_count', array(
      'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
      'index' => 'order_count',
      'filter_index' => 'pages_with_number_of_views.order_count',
      'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_roleFilter'),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('total_sales', array(
      'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Sales'),
      'index' => 'total_sales',
      'type' => 'price',
      'currency_code' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
      'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_roleFilterTotalSales'),
    ));
```

Comment: Is your question, why this column is not sortable, and how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284537/filtering-a-joined-column/15875005#15875005

Comment: this definitely can be solved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284537/filtering-a-joined-column/15875005#15875005

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the cross post, but I think we should get rid of the unanswered questions.

[Thanks to kiatng this question is answered over at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875005/1480397)

After the join, you need to add the joined field to the array `_map` declared in `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`, for example:

```
$this->_map['fields']['stock_qty'] = 'stock.qty';
```

**[edit]** As pointed out by @sh4dydud3_88, you can do this:

```
$collection->addFilterToMap('stock_qty', 'stock.qty');
```

which will add the field *stock_qty* for filtering. Then you can filter with

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('stock_qty', array('gt', 10));
```

Another example:

```
class Company_Mohe_Model_Resource_Im_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('mohe/im');
}  


public function joinIhe()
{
    $this->getSelect()->join(array('ihe' => $this->getTable('mohe/ihe')),
                                  'main_table.mic_inst_id = ihe.im_id',
                                  array('ihe_name'=>'name', 'ihe_ifms_id'=>'ifms_id')); 
    //$this->_map['fields'] = array('ihe_name'=>'ihe.name', 'ihe_ifms_id'=>'ihe.ifms_id'); //incorrect method
    $this->addFilterToMap('ihe_name', 'ihe.name'); //correct method, see comment by @sh4dydud3_88                           
    return $this;
} 
}
```